# Macdonald's notes on Kac Moody algebras

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, kac-moody-algebras

Macdonald had given some lectures on Kac-Moody algebras in 1983. The notes are typed here [by Arun Ram](http://math.soimeme.org/%7Earunram/resources.html). However, the website seems to be old and the notes are somewhat not readable because of the typeset. Does anyone have a reference to the original notes, maybe scanned somewhere/ maybe someone else has typed it up?

Comment: perhaps you can be a bit more specific about how the typed notes in Arun Ram's web site are insufficient? I would imagine the original handwritten notes to be less readable than the typed up version.

Comment: Missing portions, bad typeset